# Sorting a concordance?

Tags: python, sorting, frequency

For my homework, I need to isolate the most frequent 50 words in a text. I have tried a whole lot of things, and in my most recent attempt, I have done a concordance using this:

```
concordance = {}

lineno = 0

for line in vocab:

    lineno = lineno + 1

    words = re.findall(r'[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\'\-]*', line)
    for word in words: 
        word = word.title()
        if word in concordance:
            concordance[word].append(lineno)
        else: 
            concordance[word] = [lineno]
listing = []

for key in sorted(concordance.keys()):

    listing.append( [key, concordance[key] ])
```

What I would like to know is whether I can sort the subsequent concordance in order of most frequently used word to least frequently used word, and then isolate and print the top 50? I am not permitted to import any modules other than `re` and `sys`, and I'm struggling to come up with a solution.

Comment: Minor pythonic point: your if statement can be replaced with .setdefault().

Answer (score 1):

`sorted` is a builtin which does not require import. Try something like:

```
list(sorted(concordance.items(), key = lambda (k,v): v))[:50]
```

Not tested, but you get the idea.

The `list` constructor is there because `sorted` returns a generator, which you can't slice directly (`itertools` provides a utility to do that, but you can't import it).

There are probably slightly more efficient ways to take the first 50, but I doubt it matters here.

Comment: In this case, v is a list of line numbers.  You probably want `key=lambda (k,v): len(v)`

Comment: @mgilson Right, as I said, untested, and in any case, I wouldn't want to just give the answers to homework.

Comment: @mgilson Also, try `[1,2,3] > [1,2]`

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types

Answer (score 0):

Few hints:

- Use `enumerate(list)` in your for loop to get the line number and the line at once.
- Try using `\w` for word characters in your regular expression instead of listing `[A-Za-z...]`.
- Read about the `dict.items()` method. It will return a list of `(key, value)` pairs.
- Manipulate that list with `list.sort(key=function_to_compare_two_items)`.
- You can define that function with a `lambda`, but it is not necessary.
- Use the `len(list)` function to get the length of the list. You can use it to get the number of matches of a word (which are stored in a list).
- **UPDATE**: Oh yeah, and use slices to get a part of the resulting list. `list[:50]` to get the first 50 items (equivalent to `list[0:50]`), and `list[5:10]` to get the items from index 5 inclusive to index 10 exclusive.
- To print them, loop through the resulting list, then print every word. Alternatively, you can use something similar to `print '[separator]'.join(list)` to print a string with all the items separated by '[separator]'.

Good luck.

Comment: `dict.items()` returns a list in python 2.x and an iterator in python 3.x -- Just to avoid confusion for people using python 3.x

Comment: @mgilson Correct, if you are using python 3.x, use `list(dict.items())`. Thanks.